# How to get rid of vertical margins between lines of overflowing divs?

Tags: css, html, margin

I have a long line of inline-blocked divs that overflow to the next line. Even if I set the margins to 0, I get margins between lines: http://jsfiddle.net/szUPZ/.

[image]

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display:inline-block;
}

#container {
    width: 300px;
    height: 500px;
    border: 2px solid red;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

How can I force 0 margins for overflowing lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.add `float:left;` into `.box`

2.add `vertical-align:top` into `.box`

3.add `font-size:0px;` into `#container`

And many other methods :)

Answer (score 3):

Use vertical align top, it works for inline/inline-block elements.

```
.box {vertical-align:top}
```

Comment: But why would I need to add a vertical-align? Doesn't the div take up all the space?

Comment: By default inline/inline-block elements are middle aligned. That's why. You can try vertical-align:bottom when needed. Don't forget mark this answer as correct if your problem is solved. Thanks.